# Error instantiating generic procedure

Tags: ada

Hello i m creating generic procedure which will swap  2 numbers below is my code please help me to fix it.. i am new ada programming  please skip if any typo mistake because i m posting this questn frm mobile i dnt have net on my system

swap.ads

```
generic
   type t is private;
procedure swap(l,r:in out t);
```

swap.adb

```
procedure swap(l,r:in out t) is
   temp:t:=l;
begin
   l:=r;
   r:=temp;
end swap;
```

swap_main.adb

```
v with swap;
procedure swap_main is
   procedure swap_i is new swap(t);
   i1,i2:interger;
begin
   swap_i(i1,i2):
end swap_main;
```

Comment: We are not mind readers. What error do you get? Is it a compile time error, run time error? Which line is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside the simple typos (`v with swap`, `interger`, and the last colon): the thing about instantiating a generic is that you have to supply *actuals* for the *formals*.

In this case, you say (after adjusting case and spacing to the generally-accepted norm)

```
generic
   type T is private;
procedure Swap (L, R : in out T);
```

in which T is the formal parameter, which expects assignment and the equality operator `”=“` to be available in the actual.

But in your instantiation you say

```
procedure Swap_I is new Swap (T);
```

and the compiler says

```
rahul.ada:12:34: "T" is undefined
rahul.ada:12:34: instantiation abandoned
rahul.ada:15:04: "Swap_I" is undefined
rahul.ada:15:04: possible misspelling of "Swap_"
gnatmake: "swap_main.adb" compilation error
```

The second message explains the third. The fourth message is a failed attempt by the compiler to be helpful (`Swap_` isn’t a legal identifier, after all).

The first message is the key: there is no type `T` visible to `Swap_Main` that is satisfactory as an actual for `Swap`’s formal parameter `T`.

I think on the whole that you should have written

```
procedure Swap_I is new Swap (Integer);
```

to give you a procedure capable of swapping integers.

“Named association” ([Ada 95 Quality and Style Guide, section 5.2.2](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/95style/html/sec_5/5-2-2.html)) would make your intention clearer:

```
procedure Swap_I is new Swap (T => Integer);
```